# Doubt in bayesian theorem

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

> Is P(A|B) a function of A or B?

my doubt is P(A) is function of event A outcome. What about P(A|B)? is it funtion of A outcome? i think no right? P(A|B) is what fraction of P(A,B) in P(B)?? Please elaborate.

I am a beginer. If i am making any mistake in terminology or thinking, please correct.

$P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$

> Another doubt i have is why we wrte the above as

$P(A|B) \propto P(B|A)P(A)$

Kindly explain

Comment: What you have written is not a function at all.

Comment: sir my doubt is P(A) is function of event A outcome. What about P(A|B)? is it funtion of A outcome? i think no right? P(A|B) is what fraction of P(A,B) in P(B)?? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

In our context, $P(A|B)\propto{}P(B|A)P(A)$ means that, regarded as a function of the event $A$, $A\mapsto{}P(A|B)$ is proportional to $A\mapsto{}P(B|A)P(A)$.

In practice, in the Bayesian setting, this relationship comes to: the posterior distribution is proportional to the product of the likelihood (regarded as a function of the paramaters to infer) and of the prior distribution.

Comment: P(A|B) = percentage of intersection in P(B). Say i take two sets A and B with some intersection. Now i haveP(A|B) = P(A,B)/P(B). Now if i increase set B, fraction of intersection in B, decreases. This means P(A|B) should also depend on B(in addition to A right?). please correct if i am wrong

Comment: In a Bayesian inference, B corresponds to the available data/observations: it is known and fixed. Although $P(A|B)$ could be regarded as a function of $A$ and $B$, it should be seen as a function of $A$ for a given/known $B$ in our context.

Comment: sir any proof for that?

Answer (score 1):

$P(A)$ is the probability of event A alone (eg the probability of rain on any day)

$P(B)$ is the probability of event B alone (eg the probability of rainbow on any day)

$P(A | B)$ is the probability of event A given event B has occurred. (eg the probability rain on a day with rainbow)

$P(B | A)$ is the probability of event B given event A has occurred. (eg the probability of a rainbow on a day with rain)

All these would be just fractions or numbers.

Regarding $P(A|B)∝P(B|A)P(A)$ when the denominator increases the value ultimately decreases thus directly propotional to $P(B|A)P(A)$

Comment: So P(rain | rainbow) is function of both rain and rainbow? or only depends on event of rain?

Comment: so can i say P(A|B) function of both A and B?

Comment: I couldn't quite understand what you mean by "function of".

Comment: F(x,y) depends on x and y. Change in x or y changes F(x,y). In same  way can i consider P(A|B) = some function of A, B?

Comment: I mean P(A|B) depends on both even A and event B?

Comment: Here rain and rainbow are independent events which have their own probability. Also, both occurring at the same time is another event which has a different probability. I still don't understand why you would look at this on 'functions' level.

Comment: depends on the probability of both the events.

Comment: I was just thinking in that way. I may be wrong. So i was asking. I started probability. P(A|B) can be thought as some distribution (say normal distribution curve).

Comment: if it depends on both, then sir, why are we treating the denominator factor as some constant.(Pls correct my  thinking if erroneous or absurd)

Comment: Here the probabilities remain the same for each value of A and B and both AB. Curve for variable values maybe possible.

Comment: Kindly elaborate. If P(A|B) depends on both A and B(denominator has P(B)) , so why are we treating denominator as constant? ideally we use proportion when we exclude some constant right?

Comment: Brother, think about this scenario. In India, maybe the probability of rain today is 50% or 0.5 and rainbow would be some 0.1. This need not be the value in the USA. The values remain constant (in numerator and denominator) but the probability value may change with conditions

Comment: Sir i will take some time to think. Thank you for patiently explaining.

Comment: Anytime brother